# Will it be possible to do live video streaming in a webpage without using server side scripting or programming?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, live-streaming

Will it be possible to do live video streaming in a webpage without using server side scripting or programming?, if possible, Can anyone help me to do live video streaming in my website using jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: You seem to have confused StackOverflow with Freelancer.com

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't.

You have to have something on the server to send the video stream.

Client side code can't pick up the video from the ether.

Comment: This is false. Modern http streaming only requires the server be able to host/serve objects. The client requests each object via a GET.

Comment: @szatmary — And how is the live video supposed to get to the server?

Comment: Any protocol will do. HTTP POST, ftp, webdav, s3://.

Answer (score 0):

All you can do is involve video embedding from Youtube code snippet or other sites.
This won't require your own server.
This [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you really want you probably can stream previously encoded files. However live streaming takes encoding, which might be inefficient with JS. If you can manage encoding i.e. your webcam output in realtime by some means like FFMPEG then you can use the FileReader API to pick up the encoded video content and stream it out through a socket by a worker session.